# How to fire an event on option element click or a workaround in Chrome, Safari and Opera

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

So i already done some research and know that Chrome, Opera and Safari don't fire event on option click like FF and IE. I have read some suggestions to use on change to achieve the outcome that i want,  but was not able to get it working using onchange. To make it simple a new text has to appear when option is selected and when you select another option a new text has to appear and the old one has to vanish. So the code looks something like this and on FF and IE it works. HTML part:

```
<select required  id="topic" name="topic">
                  <option class="a01" value="1">1</option>
                  <option class="a02" value="2">2</option>
</select>

<p style="display:none;" id="a01">text1</p>
<p style="display:none;" id="a02">text2</p>
```

JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$(".a01").on('click', function() {

   $("#a02").hide();
   $("#a01").show();
});
$(".a02").on('click', function() {

   $("#a01").hide();
   $("#a02").show();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the select value on change and work with this value. Like this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () { 

  $("#topic").on('change', function() {

    var selectValue = $(this).val();

    if (selectValue  == '1') {
      $("#a02").hide();
      $("#a01").show();
    } else if (selectValue  == '2') {
      $("#a01").hide();
      $("#a02").show();
    }
  });
});

</script>
```